# Insert default value for time without timezone as hh:mm:ss format in Postgres sql

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgres sql as my database and i have a column with name event_time.
The datatype for this column is time without time zone. i want to set default value for this column as current time with hh:mm:ss format. i have used now. But output i am getting is shown below.

**17:39:33.476712**

I want the format to be only hh:mm:ss and i want to remove microsecs. So, can the format (hh:mm:ss) be achieved using now() function?

```
CREATE TABLE public.event_notifications
(
     event_time time(6) without time zone DEFAULT now(),

)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Answer (score 2):

A `time` value does not have "a format". Any format you see is applied by the application *displaying* the values in that column.

If you display the values from inside your application, then use whatever formatting functions your programming language supports.

If you want to format the values in the output of a SQL query, check the configuration of your SQL client if you can adjust the display format for `time` values.

Or include `to_char(event_time, 'hh24:mi:ss')` in your query to get the time value as a formatted string.